# How should framework/library files be treated in git?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, php

What is the best practice with versioning projects with multiple 3rd party libraries in git or other DVSC? Should the project source code be mixed with libraries in the same repository, or should they be separated somehow, or not versioned at all? Is this a good place for using submodules? I am talking about uncompiled libraries(php frameworks for example)

Comment: It's important to keep your code synchronized with whatever version of the library it depends on.  To that end, I'd definitely include the library in your repository in some fashion, so that when you check out a revision, you also get the correct version of the library.  However, PEAR's installation/include system doesn't mesh well with this.  Zend might also be awkward to use in this manner.  Works great with small libraries though.

Comment: what is elegant way to keep in sync with zend/symfony/other larger frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Use Submodules to house the libraries. If your development platform supports packages, you can forego those and just have specifications committed along with the code.

If you need to store the binaries, house the binaries in a public repo somewhere free like GitHub. The main repo can be stored in a private repo